# JMeter Http Header manager doesn't add header to request

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter plan using an HTTP sampler that I am trying to add a header to the request. The header should be really simple `custom: type`

[image: Example of project]

But when I run the test I don't see the header....

[image]

What am I missing? Why is my header not showing up in the request?

## Update

I also tried this but got the same result.

[image]

Comment: Can you show getsession?

Comment: It isn't really a valid answer because the problem wasn't the order it was the fact that it doesn't show the headers properly for invalid requests, ergo I haven't accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due to wrong [scoping](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) of Header Manager.

Either put it as child of **Get Session** or child of Test plan if it applies to whole Requests of test plan.

Example:

[image: Test Plan]

If it fails, it could be due to your User Credentials Pre-Processor (which runs before GetSession request is sent), but as you don't show code.

Another option is that you're seeing redirect request instead of initial one, check your config so that you see the 2 requests:

[image: Redirect config]

Comment: I had already tried this and it didn't help. I dragged and dropped it into the sampler but it didn't work. I will post another screenshot

Comment: It seems to not show the headers if the request itself fails still looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (When editing the HTTP Header at the thread level it would use my old values) I didn't realize I had a HTTP Header at a lower level as well. So make sure to remove any other instance of HTTP Header manager. I had one at the Thread Group level and the https request level. I deleted the one at the https level and it fixed my issue.